# Add hour to date in the mysql query result

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a query that returns a date, let's use current_date as an example:

```
SELECT
current_date();
```

I want to modify this query to return something like:

```
Date         |  Hour
2017-08-24       0
2017-08-24       1
2017-08-24       2
2017-08-24       3
2017-08-24       4
...
```

all the way to 23. I need this because i will have a different date every day and I'm trying to avoid creating a table with all dates and hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your reply. I tried with the procedure but i settled with a more simple solution. I created a auxiliar table aux_hour with numbers from 0 to 23. In my example the soltution would be:

SELECT
       current_date,
       hour
   FROM aux_hour;

That worked for me but thanks to your answer suggesting procedures i learned more about them so thank you again.

Comment: That will work just as well.  Glad to have helped you.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is to write a stored procedure to generate all the hours from a given date.  For example:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE PROCEDURE GetAllHoursInDay
(
    in in_date date
) 
BEGIN
SELECT convert (in_date, datetime)
UNION
SELECT in_date + interval 1 hour
UNION
SELECT in_date + interval 2 hour
UNION
SELECT in_date + interval 3 hour
UNION
SELECT in_date + interval 4 hour
UNION
SELECT in_date + interval 5 hour
UNION
SELECT in_date + interval 6 hour
UNION
SELECT in_date + interval 7 hour
UNION
SELECT in_date + interval 8 hour
UNION
SELECT in_date + interval 9 hour
UNION
SELECT in_date + interval 10 hour
UNION
SELECT in_date + interval 11 hour
UNION
SELECT in_date + interval 12 hour
UNION
SELECT in_date + interval 13 hour
UNION
SELECT in_date + interval 14 hour
UNION
SELECT in_date + interval 15 hour
UNION
SELECT in_date + interval 16 hour
UNION
SELECT in_date + interval 17 hour
UNION
SELECT in_date + interval 18 hour
UNION
SELECT in_date + interval 19 hour
UNION
SELECT in_date + interval 20 hour
UNION
SELECT in_date + interval 21 hour
UNION
SELECT in_date + interval 22 hour
UNION
SELECT in_date + interval 23 hour;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You can then call it e.g. by:

```
call GetAllHoursInDay(current_date());
```

Not that AFAIK MySQL does not allow a FUNCTION to return a table, so you cannot have something of the form SELECT * FROM GetAllHoursInDay.  However, you can circumvent this by creating a temporary table, filling it with the above procedure and then doing SELECT * from temptable.